# Where should a dockerized web application store uploaded files?

Tags: file-upload, docker

I'm building a web application that needs to allow users to upload profile pictures. I want the application to be self-contained, so that people don't need to have an s3 or other cloud storage service account.

It's best to keep docker containers as disposable as possible, so I guess I should create a volume. So I want the volume to be created automatically, so people don't have to specify a volume when running the container, but the documentation for the [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) instruction in dockerfiles confuses me.

> The VOLUME instruction creates a mount point with the specified name and **marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native host or other containers.**

What does it mean to be marked as such? The data is to be written by the application, it's not coming from an extenrl source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mark a volume in the dockerfile, say `VOLUME /site/uploads`,it makes it very easy to later run another container with `--volumes-from <container-name>` and have `/site/uploads` available in the new container with all the data that has been written and that will be written (if the first container is still running).

Also, you'll be able to see that volume with `docker volume ls` after you start the container the first time.

The only problem that you might have if you delete the container, is that you will lose the mapping provided by `docker inspect <container-name>` that tells you which volume your container created. To see the volume your container created really clearly and quickly, try `docker inspect <container-name> | jq '.[].Mounts'` if you have `jq` installed. Otherwise, `docker inspect <container-name> | grep Mounts -A 10` might be enough when you only have one volume. (you can also just wade through all the json yourself)

Even if you remove the container that created the volume, the volume will remain on your system, viewable with `docker volume ls` unless you run `docker volume rm <volume-name>`

Note: I'm using docker version 1.10.3

Answer (score 2):

You will not have problems with that, the images will be uploaded to the mounted filesystem without problems.

Maybe you have to specify free permissions to the uploads folder so that you can write on it.